# How to launch a .exe file and pass in a command line argument in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm wanting to launch a program and pass in a command line argument from a key press.

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.F7 Then
  Process.Start("C:\temp\test.exe"
```

This launches the program but I'm unsure on how to pass in a parameter.
The command line argument would be the same as you put in the debug section in the properties.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Don't mean to sound rude, but there're literally a thousand posts on SO showing how to run a process (including with arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Create a new [Process()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netcore-3.1) instance and set the `.StartInfo` parameters to your needs:

```
Dim P As New Process
P.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\temp\test.ext"
P.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\temp" ' sometimes you need a different working directory for an app
P.StartInfo.Arguments = "/foo:bar /n /o" ' add YOUR arguments in here
P.Start()
```

Comment: It's pretty much the same in the end but I tend to create the `ProcessStartInfo` first and then pass that to a call to `Process.Start`, which then returns the new `Process`.